# I'm seeing a new instant email-validation tool on registration forms -- is it new? And what is it?

Tags: forms, registration, email, validation

I've started to see something in the last few months that I don't remember having seen before and want to know just what it is and how it works.

When I'm required to register for some BS site (but one that doesn't make you click a validation link from an email they send), I'll often just put in a gibberish email address like asfd@asdfqwer.com. Never had a problem with this, but what I've started to see is that now some registration forms give me an error prompt *immediately after I type that in and move to the next registration field* saying "please enter a valid email address". I thought that perhaps it was somehow recognizing the invalidity of the gibberish @asdfqwer.com domain...but it's 'smarter' than that, b/c I started testing made-up addresses at known email providers, like JohnBill123987@gmail.com...and again it instantly prompts me to enter a valid email address.

I've never seen this technology before...is this a known "new" thing? And just what is this tool that's instantly, before the user even submits the registration form, testing the validity of input email addresses?

Comment: Checking the page source could give you some clues.

Comment: Hmm, I'd guess that the system either figured you out and is just blocking you; or that, they simply check the recipient at the mail server. reading material: http://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/18220/

Comment: And, you can test this out, and see this at work here: http://verify-email.org/

Comment: Could you give an example of a site using that validation? Also, if you aren't already familiar with http://www.bugmenot.com, you may find it helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about implementation or how something works from a technology stand point. I think it needs rewording.

Answer (score 0):

This is **real-time email validation service** and quite a few companies have started offering it. For example, you can take a look at [LeadSpend](https://www.edq.com/email-verification/?r=ls) real-time email verification. Quoting from their website:

> Validate emails instantly at the point of collection and make sure
>   accurate data is entering your system. Whether you’re obtaining email
>   addresses through web forms, landing pages, shopping carts or call
>   centers, real-time email validation ensures your messages are reaching
>   the inbox.

P.S - I'm not associated with LeadSpend in any way. Just quoted them as an example.

Comment: the link you posted for LeadSpend takes me to Experian's website

Comment: LeadSpend is a product by Experian. They have mentioned it at the top. (though it's very subtle)

Comment: ok. but it must be so subtle that its invisible because I cant find it

Comment: Ya, that's an IA issue. I too was confused initially.

Comment: Seems like Experian incorporated them recently. LeadSpend might be a redundant name.

Answer (score -1):

These are generally the domain names they test.

For example, they only allow Emails from say, the popular email domains such as Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook, Live, Hotmail, etc.

A popular Email service I use to keep away from Spam is [Mailinator](https://mailinator.com/)

However, some email validation forms seem to also block this particular domain for the same reason.

It is effective since for sites that have to depend on their Subscription mails and Ads on Spam, they need to be in the primary email of the user rather than one of their never opened inbox or fake emails.

PHP allows advanced Email Validation where you can also check for the legibility of an Email's domain name.

You can check on how to add a list of disallowed email domains in your form [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/13/post/2-Did-You-Mean-Advanced-Email-Validation-in-PHP.html)

Also, regarding the valid username before a valid email domain name. They happen to also check the conditions of email registration from that particular domain. For example, if you enter - in a Gmail ID, it will definitely give you an error since Gmail doesn't allow that, however Yahoo and others do. So, WRT to the domain name, the research done on validation might further go ahead to be strict in validating the email.